# Repeating pattern matching with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to validate an input with a regular expression. Up until now all my tests fail and as my experience with regex is limited I thought someone might be able to help me out.

Pattern: **digit** (*possibly* **","** **digit**) (*possibly* **;**)

A String may not begin with a ; and not end with a ;.
Digits are allowed to stand alone or with

My regEx (not working): `((\d)(,\d)?)(;?)` the problem is it does not seem to check until the end of the string. Also the optional parts are giving me headaches.

Update: `^[0-9]+(,[0-9])?(;[0-9]+(,[0-9])?)+$`this seems to work better but it does not match the single digit.

OK:

2,3;4,4;3,2

2,3

2

2,3;3;4,3

NOK:

2,3,,,,

2,3asfafafa

;2,3

2,3;;3,4

2,3;3,4;

Comment: Try [`^\d(?:[;,]\d)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pdt15G/1).

Comment: The string may not end in a semicolon.

Comment: So, `4;6;7;8` is also OK? If not, you need `^\d(?:,\d)?(?:;\d(?:,\d)?)*$`

Comment: Yes but I just noticed that this approach may not be the right one with regex. As I am continuously checking the input.. (2,) should be allowed to enter.. will need to rethink this I guess.

Comment: Maybe [`^\d(?:,\d?)?(?:;\d(?:,\d?)?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pdt15G/5) will work the way you need? Can the digits be more than one? I see you added `+`. Is `34,56` OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `^[0-9]+(,[0-9])?(;[0-9]+(,[0-9])?)+$` regex matches 1 or more digits, then an optional sequence of `,` and 1 digit, followed with *one or more* similar sequences.

You need to match *zero or more* comma-separated numbers:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:;\d+(?:,\d+)?)*$
                              ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U7jeFX/1)

Now, tweaking part:

- If only single-digit numbers should be matched, use `^\d(?:,\d)?(?:;\d(?:,\d)?)*$`
- If the comma-separated number pairs can have the second element empty, add `?` after each `,\d` (if single digit numbers are to be matched) or `*` (if the numbers can have more than one digit): `^\d(?:,\d?)?(?:;\d(?:,\d?)?)*$` or `^\d+(?:,\d*)?(?:;\d+(?:,\d*)?)*$`.